# Setting up fileserver / backup for a small organization

Tags: networking, backup, nas

I've been tasked with setting up a file sharing / backup solution for a small organization running up to three Windows boxes.  While I'm reasonably well-versed in networking things, it's not really my field and the effort here is entirely voluntary.

So as I've attempted to sort out the options, I've gathered the following issues that need to be addressed:

1. Eliminate Google Drive and adhoc drive mappings as the primary method of filesharing for internal documents
2. Provide a backup solution
3. Ensure the solution is scalable for some vaguely-defined possible future needs (like local media streaming)

As I can't anticipate what future needs will be necessary, I include #3 only because I don't want to lock myself into a solution that accommodates #1 and #2 but is otherwise not scalable (thus requiring hardware to be replaced)

That said, I've sorted through a few solutions on my own.  My first thought was to set up an Ubuntu fileserver on a NUC or something similar.  But that doesn't really solve the backup issue.

Second was using a NAS.  Certainly easier to deal with than standing up a fileserver.  Plus, some come with software to backup Windows machines.  Still, it leaves the problem of having no separate backup for the fileserver portion.

That leaves me with doing both - a separate NUC fileserver, plus a NAS to back up everything on the network.  That seems to be the cheapest, most straightforward solution to me, anyway.  The NUC would certainly provide enough power to function as a file or media server - maybe even both in a virtual configuration.

Seriously, a Pi 4 with external storage would be a big improvement - there's nothing terribly complex to address. I'm mostly just trying to sanity-check my thought process, here.

Comment: It would really help us if you specified how small your _small organization_ is. Are there few than ten people in it?

Comment: Essentially, most of the work that involves the fileserver will be done by two people.  Three Windows boxes at max would use it simultaneously.

Comment: Right. I see now that you had already specified in the question text the phrase _running up to three Windows boxes_. I have been recently working with _NAS Synology_. The System Administrator whom I have been supported was administering more than ten people, though. Maybe it is just too much for your scenario.

Comment: Yeah, that's kinda where I'm at.  I feel like they need something more, even though they probably really don't.

Maybe I should just make more creative / organized use of Google Drove / DropBox / OneDrive or something and spend a little money on a cloud subscription.  Other than the user data, there's no real point to backing up the system files...

Comment: You will really get mad using the childish Cloud Service Providers. I have tested more than fifteen of them, including _Microsoft_ _OneDrive_, _Google_ _Drive_, _A.S.U.S._ _WebStorage_, _Mega_, _Box_, _DropBox_ and the list can go on forever. They are still childish. None of them are really working well enough for real work. For photographs and movies - maybe. In the realm of backing up Operating System Images, both _EaseUs_ _Todo Backup_ and _Microsoft_ _Windows_ _Backup and Restore_ have led me nowhere. Basically, I have only performed backups so far and never got to apply a restore.